# facebook liked page (new API)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

The liked field will no longer be returned in the page property of the signed_request object for Page Tab apps created from today onwards. For apps created before today, from November 5, 2014 (90 days from today), the liked property will always return true regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.

Facebook has updated the API..
I cannot get the property of liked now. 
How can I still check like now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook forbids like-gating in their platform policies at

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse (see chapter 4.5)

from November 5th 2014 on, so you shouldn't really carry on with this kind of functionality. If you want to check if a user liked a certain page for other reasons, you can use the

```
/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}
```

endpoint for this (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes). But be aware that you need the `user_likes` permission, which is bound to an app review from Facebook.

Comment: And by bound to app review means that user_likes will never get approved if you want it to do like-gating